# Как запустить файл, не сохранённый на диске

Tags: python-3.x, сжатие

Ситуация:
Есть файл, (к примеру test.txt), он сжимается алгоритмом хаффмана (написанный мной), сохраняется в папку.
И если я его запущу как обычный .txt файл, логично что внутри будет не та информация. (Т.к меняется бинарный код файла, и инфа в нём измениться, а windows не знает, что файл был сжат, и по какому принципу и тд.)
А если через программу его распаковать (опять же, через ту которой сжимался, т.е моей), то как запустить, не сохраняя лишний файл? Или так нельзя?
А если буду сжимать не .txt?
P.S Сжимаю бинарный код файла.
Короче говоря, есть ли какой-то способ загрузить файл в оперативную память (запустить файл не сохраняя на диске), с использованием python'а и модулей (логично)?
От вас - название модулей, либо в каком направлении двигаться (м.б я вообще не туда копаю)

Comment: Может в Temp сохранять и после открыть его?

Comment: Вариант хорош, но всё равно придётся лишний файл сохранять :(

Comment: Тогда сделать свою программу текстовый редактор. Вы через нее откроете файл своего формата и отобразите расшифрованное содержимое. Тогда не придется сохранять в другом файле